# Code execution blocked with Factory.StartNew

Tags: c#

Factory.StartNew leads to code execution blockage when I don't used Thread.Sleep(20);

I tried the following:

- `Thread.Sleep()` - This works with Factory.StartNew & produces desirable result
- `Task.Delay(20)` -  This doesn't work with Factory.StartNew
- `Task<bool>.Run` - Using this instead of Factory.StartNew doesn't make any difference

The code:

```
private async Task<bool> GetStatus()
{                        
  var MyTask = Task<bool>.Factory.StartNew( () => 
  //var MyTask = Task<bool>.Run( () => // Using Task.Run doesn't make any 
  //difference
  {
    while (true)
    {              
      if (EventStatus.ToString() == "Rejected")
        break;
      if (EventStatus.ToString() == "Error")
        break;
      Thread.Sleep(20);// This gives the desirable result.Removing it 
                       //causes application to hang
      //Task.Delay(20);// This line doesn't make any difference
    }                
    return true;
   });            
  MyTask.Wait();            
  return await MyTask;
}
```

If I use Task.Factory.StartNew without using Thread.Sleep(20) code gets stuck in endless loop.

How can I improve code and get it to work without using Thread.Sleep(20) ?

I tried Task.Factory.StartNew specifying TaskScheduler but that caused code to hang too.

Comment: Could it be because `Task.Delay` is awaitable, and you're not awaiting it?

Comment: What is `EventStatus`? Does it use proper lock? Otherwise C# may be allowed to read it only once, but not on every loop iteration.

Comment: EventStatus is updated everytime a callaback event fires.  No, I'm not using any lock, I'll explore this option. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

First, don't use `StartNew`. It's [dangerous](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html). Use `Task.Run` instead.

Second, the reason you're seeing and endless loop is that `Task.Delay` just starts a timer and returns a task that completes when that timer fires. If you want the code to actually *wait for* the timer, then you need to `await` that task. Also, `EventStatus` is being accessed from multiple threads without protection, which is not good. You'll need to add a lock to fix this permanently:

```
private async Task<bool> GetStatus()
{
  var task = Task.Run(async () =>
  {
    while (true)
    {              
      // TODO: add lock for EventStatus
      if (EventStatus.ToString() == "Rejected")
        break;
      if (EventStatus.ToString() == "Error")
        break;
      await Task.Delay(20);
    }                

    return true;
  });

  return await task;
}
```

As a final note, I would get rid of this entirely. Instead of polling for `EventStatus` to change, make it an actual "signal". E.g., assuming `EventStatus` is set once, then a `TaskCompletionSource<bool>` would work fine.